# unconfigured column family in <Tablename>

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to usu Mapper class in datastax classes, but having "unconfigured column family in USER_CERT"

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured columnfamily "USER_CERT"
    at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:41)
    at com.datastax.driver.mapping.Mapper.saveQuery(Mapper.java:182)
    at com.ttech.tims.operation.main.CassandraMain.testNewDataStaxMapper(CassandraMain.java:170)
```

**Here is my class file**

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Column;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.PartitionKey;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Table;

@Table(name = "\"USER_CERT\"", readConsistency = "QUORUM", writeConsistency = "QUORUM", caseSensitiveTable = true,caseSensitiveKeyspace=true)
public class UserCert_New {

   private static void testNewDataStaxMapper(Session session2) {    
      Mapper<UserCert_New> userCertMapper;          
      MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session); 

      userCertMapper = manager.mapper(UserCert_New.class);          
      userCertMapper.saveQuery(new UserCert_New("905332108062", "type", "crt", "12"));
   }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What does your table definition/schema look like?

Comment: problem was about quotation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that there is a bug while creating Mapper and saving entity object at 3.0.3 ,

I have upgraded it into 3.1.0 then solved the problem.